# In VBA, how does the [DoTransaction] option work in regards to the DoCmd.RunSQL option

Tags: sql, vba

OK so I know that in VBA with Microsoft Access I can use `DoCmd.RunSQL` to run SQL commands against my database.

Whenever you type this, the VBA equivalent to intellisense suggests a second parameter called [DoTransaction] as shown below:

[image: VBA Screenshot]

VBA doesn't suggest any possible values for this option so it isn't an enum, nor is it a boolean so what is it and how does it work?

Thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194626.aspx. I suggest you use `Set db = CurrentDB; db.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnerror` rather than RunSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*UseTransaction* Optional **Variant**

Use **True** (–1) to include this query in a transaction. Use **False** (0) if you don't want to use a transaction. If you leave this argument blank, the default (**True**) is assumed.

*transaction*: A series of changes made to a database's data and schema. If any elements of the transaction fail, the entire transaction fails and data is "rolled back." to how it was before the changes